# Sending Outlook Meeting email from outside (e.g. Symfony) and "retrieving answers"

Tags: php, symfony, email, outlook

We have developed a Symfony 2.8 based SaaS for project management.

We would like to integrate with MS Outlook (or any other system like Gmail that is compatible with "meeting").

At the moment we have created an ICS that can be shared as read only. No issues here.

What we are trying to do at the moment is sending invitations for meetings created inside our system, with the possibility as usually for the user to answer "accept, decline". We then need to process those returned emails and take the appropriate measures.

Which is the format of the email to be sent to be treated as meeting?

Is there any library in PHP that manages that?

Thank you

Comment: Since there is no standard format or protocol or procedure for such task there is no native implementation in php. Your best bet is to use a web any based groupware solution and embed links for accept or decline to the email messages you send out. That way the messages will work in any email client too which typically is _not_ the case with some specific notification email format you pick. I know, not convenient, but that is the situation that emerges when companies pushing their groupware to the market ignore standards by purpose...

Comment: I appreciate the hack, but what I need is the possibility for the user to really click on "accept" or "refuse" in MS Outlook. There must be a way to create an email with the exact content to perform the operation. Google seems to have solved the problem since from Gmail you can accept MS Office invitations to meeting, and it will add to your calendar

Comment: Yes, it is possible to implement an invitation email such that it works in MS-Outlook. The issue is that it will not work in any other email client. Which actually is desired by MS.

Comment: If it works on MS Outlook (hence also in Gmail) it's a good starting point for me. Any idea on the format to use? Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: AFAI understood long ago when still dealing with that stuff You just attach a ICAL file. Take care to attach it in MS-Outlook naming style, so breaking the mime standards. MS-Outlook will then automatically add those fancy buttons. You don't actually have to code those. (as said: from memory)

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try! ;)